# Javascript Matrix and distance calculation

Tags: javascript, matrix, distance

I have a problem maybe someone can help me. 
This is my code :    when I am trying to calculate distance I can use my function for normal variable that I gave it:   `document.write(getDistance(45,35,41,35));`   but when I called from my matrix  is 
not working do you know what is problem?  `document.write(getDistance(parseFloat($m.rows[0][3]),parseFloat($m.rows[1][3]),parseFloat($m.rows[0][4]),parseFloat($m.rows[1][4])));`

tnx

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Matrix() {
    this.rows = new Array();
}
var $m = new Matrix();
$m.rows[0] = new Array(1, 10, 45,41 );
$m.rows[1] = new Array(2, 5, 35,35 );
$m.rows[2] = new Array(3, 8, 41,40 );


alert($m.rows[1][2]);

//Calculate the shortest distance based on lat and long
function getDistance(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2){
    var R = 6371; //KM
    var d = Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) +
            Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lon2 - lon1)) * R
        return d    
};

document.write(getDistance(parseFloat($m.rows[0][3]),parseFloat($m.rows[1][3]),parseFloat($m.rows[0][4]),parseFloat($m.rows[1][4])));
document.write(getDistance(45,35,41,35));




    </SCRIPT>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing an invalid element in your matrix:

```
parseFloat($m.rows[1][4])
```

Your matrix is a 4x4, but you are accessing the fifth value in the second row.